# What is the Performance DC for feats with the "Combat Performance" tags?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, difficulty-class

What is the Performance DC  for feats with the "Combat Performance" tags?

Example: [Dramatic Display feat](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Dramatic%20Display)

What is the Performance DC that you add the +2 to skill check from the feat that gives you a +2 to attack rolls till the end of your next turn?

Answer (score 3):

Performance feats are specifically for [performance combat](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/performance-combat), e.g. sparring, an exhibition match, gladiatorial combat, etc. In such a fight, you get an option to use a swift action to make a “performance [combat] check” to hype up the crowd. The effects and DCs for doing so are part of the performance combat rules. Performance feats only apply to such fights, and often revolve around this check, making it do more or giving alternate options to just amping up the crowd.

In particular, Dramatic Display says that when you make that performance check, you get +2 on that check as well as some other bonuses for the rest of the round. It doesn’t care if you succeed or not, and you’re not making a separate check just for Dramatic Display. You’re making a performance check for some other reason, as described in the performance combat rules and/or some other performance feat, using the DC that’s appropriate for the check you’re making, and then you’re getting extra bonuses above and beyond whatever the original effect of the check was.

Since these feats only apply during performance combat, they’re worthless for most Pathfinder characters. Only in highly themed games where every combat is in front of a crowd are they worth even considering. Even in such a game, Dramatic Display is a mediocre feat.

Comment: Note that the Performing Combatant feat lets you use a performance combat feat in regular fights, if you succeed on a DC 20 performance check. It doesn't make the performance feats good in such circumstances considering the opportunity cost of not taking another feat, however.

Comment: Good catch sideromancer. This is for a Flashy build with the inspiration of Captain America doing trick throws with a throwwing shield that has distance and returning on it with other feats to make look flashy...errr? LOL